# Custom shipping method break cart page render

Tags: shipping, custom

I try to create a new custom shipping method, following the tutorial below: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/

In the administrative panel, it appears normally. I was already receiving this error on the cart page.

`Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Alfasoft\LuandaShipping\Model\Carrier\LuandaShipping does not exist #0 /home/beatrizfranck/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Alfasoft\\Luanda...')`

So I ran `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and then the page re-rendered. But only with one sentence. `Calculate delivery charges`. I tried to view and create the di.xml file because I thought this could be the problem, but nothing I did solved the problem.

My shipping method need to be appear on this area:

[image]

And this area:

[image]

I'm using Magento 2.2.3 with Cogito theme and Ecomteck Store Pickup shipping method. Any ideias?

Comment: Hey, can you post your code or some of it? Might be easier for others to help. Specially where you use this Class Alfasoft\LuandaShipping\Model\Carrier\LuandaShipping.

Comment: Hi Rui, i finaly solved this. I make tutorial again and its works. When i make tutorial, I change some class names and ids. This causes the bug.

Comment: Yeah I know the feeling, sometimes it can be a simple think that is overlooked, but glad you could fix it